# iOS / xcode - NSNumber literal updates being ignored by Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsnumber

1) I declare a NSNumber property is a view controller header file `@property NSNumber *myNumber;`
2) I set that property to a NSNumber literal and log the output:

```
self.myNumber = @9;
NSLog(@"myNumber is: %@", self.myNumber);
```

3) The above works as expected. Then I change the @9 to @10. and run the program. **It does not work, the property is still set to a value of 9**.

4) I make a small change to the NSLog text (a space, a full stop, anything) then rerun the program. **It now does work!** (updating to the new value, e.g. @10)

Any thoughts on why this is happening would be MUCH appreciated, thanks

Comment: Tried a clean (Cmd-shift-K)?

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot. Bit of a newbie so thought I might be doing something wrong with NSNumber...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, Xcode gets stuck on little things like this. When something weird like this happens, the first thing to try is a clean - <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>.